# Сто вопросов в день!

Tags: обсуждение, stackoverflow, stackexchange, вехи

На этой неделе произошло поистине историческое событие, наше сообщество впервые в своей истории достигло [ста вопросов в день](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41168/stack-overflow-in-russian)! ([Как считается этот показатель.](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5883/))

**Поздравляю, Коллеги!**

Все было бы прекрасно, но…

[image: 100!]

Мы не только достигли ста вопросов в день, но и подвинули с пятого места не кого-нибудь, а [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), сообщество «[трилогии](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/the-stack-overflow-trilogy/)»!

От лица русскоязычных программистов, тех людей, которые находят помощь в сообществе, получая ответ на свой вопрос или читая ответ к уже заданному, хочу выразить огромную благодарность всем знатокам, кто день за днем меняет действительность, делая Интернет лучшим местом для получения качественно развернутого ответа на технический вопрос! Мы движемся верным курсом.

Уверен, вашим примером вдохновятся многие! Спасибо!

Comment: Всего в не англоязычных сообществах Stack Overflow задается почти 200 вопросов в день: 100 – Stack Overflow на русском, 80 – Stack Overflow em Português, 15 – スタック・オーバーフロー.

Comment: Причем относительная активность (totalUsers / QperDay   (т.е. количество пользователей требуемых для одного вопроса в день)) у нас вообще самая высокая, вдвое выше, чем на enSO. / А вот у японцев совсем беда...

Comment: Ну мы крутые. :)

Comment: и 80% отвеченных (вчера было 79%)

Comment: @PashaPash, причем если посмотреть что иногда "Дух сообщества" открывает - есть вопросы, которые отвечены, просто ответы не помечены галочкой... Вот бы их позакрывать (ну или может разрешить пользователям с большим рейтингом их зарывать)... Вот тогда показатель взлетит еще выше :)

Comment: Здорово было бы увидеть  в  статистике сайта на главной странице индикатор "вопросов в день".

Comment: @AnatolyNikolaev Не получится, к сожалению. Статистика в боковой панели тянется с Зоны 51.