# Новая эра сообщества: теперь без беты!

Tags: поддержка, аттестация, вехи

Поздравляю, коллеги! Мы сделали ещё один большой шаг на нашем нелегком пути. Сообщество прошло аттестацию – «бета» остается позади!

За менее чем восемь месяцев после «перезапуска» сайта как части [Stack Exchange](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/06/welcome-nicolas-chabanovsky-and-stack-overflow-in-russian/), сообщество Stack Overflow на русском заслуженно стало одним из самых активных среди всей Сети – мы твердо [заняли](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1460/) пятую строчку по количеству [вопросов в день](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday). И, уверен, это только начало!

Количество вопросов в день – это лишь показатель, но не цель. Наша цель – создание свободно распространяемой базы прикладных решений, которую можно собрать лишь вместе, всем сообществом русскоязычных разработчиков программного обеспечения. Именно реальные вопросы от реальных программистов могу показать, какие знания нужны отрасли сегодня. Аттестация дает нам право считать, что мы крепко встали на ноги и достойны отправиться в нелегкое, но крайне увлекательное путешествие по построению нашего общего «[города знаний](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1146/)» под названием «Stack Overflow на русском».

Спасибо вам за то, что вы делаете для коллег, русскоязычных разработчиков программного обеспечения и энтузиастов программирования! Хочу подчеркнуть, что это не мое «спасибо», это благодарность самих коллег – большинство посетителей конференций, где я был, подходили ко мне лишь сказать «спасибо за сайт, без вас было бы тяжко». Уверен, все эти «спасибо» были адресованы именно Вам!

Аттестация привнесет несколько изменений.

#### Новые пороговые значения для привилегий

Аттестация означает и новые требования к участникам сообщества – они должны быть более опытными. Сразу же после того, как пропадет знак «беты», [возрастут пороговые значения для получения привилегий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1216/).

#### Возможность проведения выборов

Каждый сайт сети Stack Exchange самодостаточен и управляется сообществом. Прохождение аттестации говорит о том, что в сообществе появились достойные сильные личности, которые могут служить примером для остальных и поддерживать баланс на пути развития. Сообщество сможет сделать свой выбор в самое ближайшее время. Выборы в модераторы сообщества, с большой вероятностью, начнутся на следующей неделе.

Если вы не знакомы с процессом выбора, пожалуйста, обратите внимание на публикацию «[Что такое выборы в модераторы и как они работают?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1983/)».

---

В самое ближайшее будущее планируется опубликовать рассказ о достижениях нашего сообщества в блоге компании. Как мне кажется, было бы здорово поделиться реальным опытом использования сайта. Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш опыт использования сайта! Поделитесь тем, что вы узнали нового, как коллеги помогли вам или как вы смогли помочь им! В общем, всем тем, что мотивирует вас быть частью сообщества  Stack Overflow на русском!

Comment: По поводу опыта — в процессе ответа на вопросы левелапнулся по многим темам. «Объяснил раз, объяснил два, уже и самому понятно стало.»

Comment: И да — УРААААА!

Comment: блин, я лишился всего того, чем никогда не пользовался, как дальше жить? придется дальше ответы в комментах писать ))

Comment: [Наша страница на Area 51 на момент аттестации сайта.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41168/stack-overflow-in-russian)

Answer (score 29):

Поздравляю всех нас с этим достижением! За эти восемь месяцев мы:

- Перевели сайт. Причем около 95% работы было сделано буквально за считанные недели энтузиастами с Хэшкода (и одним фрилансером, насколько я помню), так что сайт вышел в Бету вполне переведённым и пригодным к использованию. Ура этим энтузиастам! С тех пор мы исправили множество мелких недочетов, улучшили формулировки во множестве мест, затребовали пачку изменений от разработчиков SO, переработали с десяток статей справки и даже написали парочку новых. Мы бились с падежами, числами и родами нашего прекрасного языка, который не укладывается в англоязычные шаблоны. До сих пор движок преподносит нам сюрпризы в виде внезапно слетающих переводов, но мы справляемся.
- Определили тематику сайта. Мы обсудили домашние задания, администрирование, железо, инспекцию кода (рекордная поддержка!), документацию. Придумали свой велосипед для списков литературы! Мы поменяли причины закрытия, порадовались этому, пожалели об этом и даже кое-что вернули на место.
- Задали около 20 000 новых вопросов и на большинство из них нашли решения.
- Улучшили и переработали содержимое сайта. Проверили тысячи старых (и новых) вопросов, на некоторые дали ответ, другие закрыли. Сначала этот процесс улучшил наши формальные показатели на Area 51 и реальное качество вопросов. Потом он породил «молчаливых закрывателей», не читающих Мету. Рефлексия системы ответила на него «отрядом открывашек», мы даже устроили жаркий спор в чате. Оглядываясь назад, я думаю, что этот конфликт мы разрешили конструктивно и теперь лучше понимаем друг друга.
- Сделали описания меток. В них всегда есть, над чем работать, но и на основном сайте, и на Мете первые несколько страниц меток сделаны хорошо. Мы даже однажды устроили партизанскую вылазку на Мету en.SO по поводу плагиата в описаниях меток.
- Выдержали летнюю сессию и внезапный наплыв новых участников где-то в середине сентября.
- Уделали по количеству вопросов в день Server Fault и сотню других сайтов сети.
- Придумали собственное имя для участника номер ноль. Серьезно, на большинстве сайтов он просто Community user, а у нас — Дух сообщества!
- Завершили Бету всего за 8 месяцев! Не могу утверждать, что это рекорд (но подозреваю).

Ещё раз ура!

Мои отдельные поздравления от имени всех новых участников — нашему менеджеру сообщества Nicolas Chabanovsky и всем участникам, которые пришли с сайта Hashcode.ru. Для вас этот путь начался ещё несколько лет назад. Знаю, вам было сложно с нами, новичками, которые боролись за власть и бунтовали, выкашивали старые вопросы, переделали и позакрывали всё, что смогли. =) Спасибо вам за богатое наследство вопросов и ответов! Совместными усилиями мы сделали сайт ещё лучше.

Рад, что мы все участники одного большого сообщества.

Comment: Самое смешное со скоростью прохождения стадии беты — это то, что изначально на Area 51 закладывалось, что сайты будут проходить все стадии за пару месяцев. Кстати, не совсем корректно соревноваться в скорости выхода из беты с остальными, потому что у нас импортированы и Q&A, и юзеры полноценного сайта. Не было бы импорта — не было бы скорого выхода из беты.

Comment: @Discord, но ведь не только у нас импортированы?

Comment: @Qwertiy Не слышал о столь масштабных импортах. И вообще об импортах, если уж на то пошло.

Answer (score 17):

Славно поманьячили, я считаю. Каждый нашёл что-то своё: @Vlad и @PashaPash маньячили в ответах, @iRumba и @Вася маньячили в вопросах, @NormalHuman и @Discord маньячили в тревогах, @AlexanderBarakin маньячил в проверках, @Nofate маньячил в модераторской, @NickVolynkin маньячил в Мете, @NicolasChabanovsky маньячил в мета-постах... всех не перечислить! (А также не всё доступно на Data.SE...)

Да что там — у нас 1 эпический юзер, 13 флудеров в чате и 39 фанатиков! С такой командой не пропадём.

Маньячили, маньячим и будем маньячить. Вперёд, к новым свершениям!

А пока — празднуем!

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Приятно видеть, как ru SO постепенно растёт и накапливает знания. Ещё приятнее понимать, что и сам приложил к этому руку.

Радует, что у нас, по сравнению с тем же en SO, как-то всё демократичнее и добрее.

Я на сайте уже давно и замечаю постепенную динамику к систематизации и упорядочиванию знаний. Не перестаю удивляться, сколько времени люди посвящают SO, что не может не радовать.

Мне приятно, что я являюсь частью сообщества, что помогаю другим людям. Да и отвечая на многие вопросы мы тем самым так же систематизируем и свои знания и открываем что-то новое для себя.

В общем, всем спасибо и давайте сделаем ru SO ещё лучше (:

Answer (score 9):

Я хочу выразить благодарность сообществу.
На все! вопросы я здесь находил ответы, даже когда изъяснялся, может, и не совсем чётко, меня направляли в нужное русло и подсказывали план дальнейших действий. Я учился программированию сам и когда возникали вопросы (а их было,поверьте, очень много) -очень большой вклад внёс Ваш сайт.
В течении нескольких часов, максимум до суток мои вопросы разрешались. Я восхищён создателями сайта и людьми, которые мне помогали.

Чем могу-всегда рад помочь :)
Спасибо Вам огромное.
Желаю дальнейшего развития, грандиозных идей и их реализации.

Answer (score 6):

Итак, мы всем сообществом теперь являемся полноценным участником сообщества сообществ StackExchange, что свидетельствует уже о том, что в нашем сообществе есть необходимость и те, кто на эту необходимость готов ответить собственным вкладом.

У нас есть новички, задающие вопросы, у нас есть ядро опытных пользователей, которые на вопросы в основном отвечают, реже задают.

#### Но нам всё ещё есть куда расти.

Сообщество всё ещё находится не на самом хорошем счету среди русскоязычных специалистов. Во всяком случае, у всех, кто лично мне это высказывал. *Проблема* [известна (вы только взгляните на количество и длину ответов!)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/173/181100) и хочется верить, что будет слабеть по мере роста сообщества.

**StackOverflow на русском** уже полезен своей базой знаний. И если её продолжать расширять с сохранением всех принятых здесь принципов, специалисты начнут чаще на неё натыкаться, это сделает её известнее, что, в конце концов, должно эту *проблему* решить.

Со своей стороны, я буду продолжать отвечать на хорошие вопросы (в рамках моей компетенции, которые я постепенно расширяю). StackOverflow на русском уже не первое сообщество, где я этим занимаюсь, и я достаточно себя зарекомендовал в ряде мест, чтобы мне писали вопросы лично. Обычно я не отвечаю и прошу опубликовать вопрос в каком-нибудь профильном сообществе, если ответ может быть полезен не только мне. Но в них обычно сталкиваюсь с отсутствием *инструментов для противодействия вопросам-дубликатам*. Возможно, теперь стану перенаправлять сюда. Во всяком случае, **здесь у меня есть ощущение, что если я уйду из сообщества, мои ответы будут искать и находить.**