# Обнуление рейтинга

Tags: обсуждение, бета

Правда ли что , сайт `ru.stackoverflow.com` находится в бете, и когда он выйдет из беты рейтинг будет обнулён у всех пользователей ?

Comment: нет не правда, сайт уже давно не в бете, обнуления рейтинга при выходе не было

Comment: Откда такие слухи? )

Comment: когда узнал про мету, несколько месяцев назад, прочитал в какой-то теме. не могу найти её сейчас. может что напутал.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

StackOverflow на русском **вышел из беты 11 декабря 2015** (согласно дате публикации [тематического анонса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1985/208074)).

В придачу, Area 51 (платформа для создания и продвижения сообществ StackExchange) [сообщает](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41168/stack-overflow-in-russian) следующее:

> This site has
>
> **Launched!**
>
> This Stack Exchange site`s beta was successful, so it launched 1 year ago.

В переводе:

> Данный сайт был
>
> **Запущен!**
>
> Бета-период данного сайта на Stack Exchange прошёл успешно, а потому он был выпущен в свет 1 год назад.