# Итоги 2015 года

Tags: обсуждение, итоги-года

В преддверии Нового Года, мы бы хотели подвести итоги уходящего.

В этом году в сообществе произошло очень много изменений, что крайне трудно выделить наиболее важное. В этом году мы:

- Перезапустили сообщество, мигрировав на платформу Stack Exchange. Это было совсем недавно! Датой перезапуска можно считать первое апреля.
- Провели три встречи сообщества: в Санкт-Петербурге, Москве и Новосибирске.
- [Стали](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1460/) пятым сообществом в сети Stack Exchange [по количеству задаваемых вопросов в день](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday), перейдя отметку 100 вопросов.
- Повысили процент отвеченных вопросов до *85%*!
- [Прошли аттестацию](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1985/).
- [И в завершении года, успешно провели выборы модераторов.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2226/)

Это действительно сильно! К примеру, сравните показатели за этот и прошлый год:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
|                    | ХэшКод за 2014 год |  Stack Overflow   |
|                    |                    |  на русском c 1го |
|                    |                    |  апреля 2015го.   |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|  Задано вопросов   |      16 712        |       28 160      |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|Опубликовано ответов|      16 737        |       34 117      |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|  Новых участников  |       9 000        |       19 006      |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|     Уникальных     |     3 500 000      |     3 400 000     |
|   пользователей    |                    |                   |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|   Просмотренных    |    11 000 000      |     13 647 546    |
|      страниц       |                    |                   |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Казалось бы, это всего лишь цифры, которые заметно меньше, чем в англоязычном сообществе. Но представьте, лишь в ноябре более 3 000 реальных людей, наших коллег, не просто задали вопрос, а получили ответы-решения, а чтобы прочитать тот же объем информации, что был «поглощен» всеми пользователями сайта за ноябрь, потребуется нанять на полный рабочий день на месяц 23 000 разработчиков.

*И все это благодаря именно нам!*

Уверен, это не предел! В следующем году нам есть над чем работать.

- Встречи сообщества. Повторить прошедшие и провести новые! Согласно статистике, Stack Overflow на русском наиболее популярен в (по убыванию): Москве, Киеве, Санкт-Петербурге, Минске и Харькове. Если в сообществе есть активные участники из Киева и Минска, было бы здорово провести следующие встречи у вас!
- Увеличение количества вопросов в день. На мой взгляд, следующий большой шаг в развития Stack Overflow на русском может случиться в случае персональных рекомендаций знатоков использовать сайт для решения прикладных задач на работе. Этот шаг крайне важен не только для Stack Overflow, но и для всего русскоязычного сообщества, так как он подтолкнет к: а) публикации в открытый доступ знаний, которых еще нигде нет; б) профессиональному общению между разработчиками. Уверен, оба этих следствия положительно повлияют как на индустрию в целом, так и на личное профессиональное развитие конкретных индивидов.
- Улучшение переводов интерфейса и справочного центра.
- Улучшение существующих правил сообщества и добавление новых.

Да, еще нам надо решить проблему индексации и ранжирования сайта поиском Яндекса, но это отдельная длиииинная история…

В завершении, спешу поздравить всех участников и пользователей Stack Overflow на русском с наступающим Новым Годом!

[А чтобы праздники «не прошли за зря», предлагаем вам принять участие в игре…](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2235/).

Comment: @NormalHuman Спасибо за замечания! Поправил.

Comment: Сравнивать 12 и 8 месяцев немного неудобно.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, не придирки ради, а справедливости для: я считаю, что в данном тексте «Вам» должно быть «вам», т.к. текст является обращением ко всем, а не к конкретному пользователю. Я, в целом, понимаю, что таким образом Вы хотели подчеркнуть вклад именно читающего этим строки, но, на мой взгляд, это некорректно.

Comment: @ixSci Да, вы правильно заметили, что это именно личное обращение. С маленькой буквы как-то двузначно. Заменил на «нам».

Comment: @NickVolynkin В следующем году, обязательно сравним за полный год!

Comment: *Повысили процент отвеченных вопросов до 85%!* вообще-то, согласно [общей статистике](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday) у нас пока лишь 83% отвеченных. что примерно подтверждает и наш [«внутренний» учёт](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1340/178576).

Comment: @NickVolynkin: вот [по годам статистика](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/419383/yearly-stats?year=2015&opt.textResults=true), взято [отсюда](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/01/year-in-review-2015/)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky и ведь сравнили!